# Regex in C# , Expression in negative lookbehind

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I`m trying to write an expression to match a single quote preceded by an odd number of question marks.

I have found a negative look-behind expression to match a single question mark

```
pattern (?<!\?)'

aaa?'aaa   match
aaa'aaaa   not match
aaa??'aaa  match --wrong
```

But what I need is to detect an odd number of question marks, not just one.
I tried to put it like `(?<!\?(??))'` but it did not work.

The result I want is

```
aaa?'aaaa  match
aaa??'aaaa  not match
aaa???'aaaa  match
aaa????'aaaa  not match
aaa?????'aaaa  match
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you are looking for is `(?<=(^|[^?])(\?\?)*\?)'`.

Let's break the lookbehind (I changed it to positive) down:

```
(^|[^?]) not a question mark (possibly also start of string, i.e. nothing)
(\?\?)*  any number of question mark pairs
\?       a single question mark
```

So in order for the quote to match, it has to be preceded by these tokens in reverse order. It should be clear that this forces the number of preceding question marks to be exactly 2N + 1 for some N >= 0.

Comment: Should check for possible start of input as well, otherwise only matches if they are not at the start of the string.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to use any lookaround for this matching. Try this one:

```
([^\?]|^)\?(\?\?)*([^\?]|$)
```

It is checking whether the `?` sign is in between the non question mark sign or at the end of start of the string.

Though I am not sure what will happen for the input like `aaa?????'aaaa??`

Comment: Good advice about lookaround: it should never be the first tool you reach for, especially lookbehinds.  But there's a legitimate use for it here.  Change your `([^\?]|^)` back to `(?<!\?)` like the OP had it, and you don't have to handle the start of string as a special case.  Also, if you read the question again you'll see that your `([^\?]|$)` should be simply `'` (apostrophe/single quote).